# Read serialized java object from disk with newer class?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Just a simple question:

If I saved a java object on disk, but after that I added some more data member (String type), can new class read those old java object back with those new String member as null?

Comment: Did you explicitly set a `serialVersionUID` field in your original object?

Comment: Yes, I do. There is one generated, and never changed.

Comment: Then yes, what you say is exactly what will happen.  One question however - since it's such a simple thing, why didn't you just _try it?_ :)

Comment: Sorry.. I thought this is simple enough, and someone must know it just like a snap. Though I should try it out by muself. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See [Versioning of Serialized Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html) in the Object Serialization Specification.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but for that you need to manage compatibility actively. You need to ensure that the new class has the same `serialVersionUID` value as the old class. This `private static final long serialVersionUID` field can be auto-generated - or manually assigned. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

If you already have a `serialVersionUID`, the new field will be null.

If you don't, you want to create one and use the same value as the auto-generated value of the old class. That's what the tool `serialver` is for.